# Import Data From csv Into Postgresql WITHOUT COPY

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, csv, python

I am writing a function for a `python` environment which needs to import data from a `csv` file into an existing table. The scope in which the function can execute does not allow for a db SUPERUSER to run the function and so the `COPY` function is out of the question.

What other options are efficient?

The files range from 100,000 to 1,000,000 rows.

This question has also been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499969/import-data-from-csv-into-postgresql-without-copy)

Comment: x-posted http://stackoverflow.com/q/40499969/398670

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328